# Cannot match if condition

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Basically, I'm trying to read a BIOS setting and then with the `if` condition, if it matches to execute another command.

It works fine with other variables, it is just with this one.

```
#This Script will check for VT and VTD on Lenovo machines and enable them
#if the current value is disabled. 
#Run Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted first.
#Run As administrator

#Check the current values
$VT= gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi |
     Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(",",[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -eq "VirtualizationTechnology"} |
     Format-List CurrentSetting
$VTD= gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi |
      Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(",",[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -eq "VTdFeature"} |
      Format-List CurrentSetting

#Modify the values
#$EnabledVT= (gwmi -class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -namespace root\wmi).SetBiosSetting("VirtualizationTechnology,Enable")
#$EnableVTD= (gwmi -class Lenovo_SetBiosSetting -namespace root\wmi).SetBiosSetting("VTdFeature,Enable")
#$SaveBios=(gwmi -class Lenovo_SaveBiosSettings -namespace root\wmi).SaveBiosSettings()

#Check if VT is disabled and enable it if it is. 
Echo "Virtualization current settings are below"
Write-output $VT
IF ($VT -like "*Disable*") {
  "this is not working"
} else {
  "Setting is already set to enabled, no changes made."
}

#Check if VTD is disabled and enable it if it is. 
Write-output $VTD
IF ($VTD -like "*,Disable") {
  this is not working
} else {
  "Setting is already set to enabled, no changes made."
}

#Save bios settings.
$SaveBios

Write-host "Check completed, Please restart computer for changes to take effect if any changes were made. "
```

I have tried different conditions to match exactly  or the like or the match but nothing seems to be able to find anything.

Comment: Don't pipe to `Format List`. The `Format-` cmdlets should be used for displaying information, not for storing it in a variable for use later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Format-List`, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
$VT  = gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -eq “VirtualizationTechnology”} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CurrentSetting
$VTD = gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -eq “VTdFeature”} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CurrentSetting
```

Answer (score 4):

So, here's the issue that you are having. You are piping the output of your command to `Format-List`, and storing that info in your variable. Don't do that. The `Format-*` cmdlets should be used to format things for output to the console, not for storing data for use later. Instead remove that part, and then reference the `CurrentSetting` property of the object.

```
$VT= gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -eq “VirtualizationTechnology”}
$VTD= gwmi -class Lenovo_BiosSetting -namespace root\wmi | Where-Object {$_.CurrentSetting.split(“,”,[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) -eq “VTdFeature”}

IF ($VT.CurrentSetting -like "*Disable*") {"this is now working"}
    else {"Setting is already set to enabled, no changes made."}
```

This will function as desired.